# Jquery selector to generate total where checkbox is ticked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to create a dynamic total generator, which adds a value to the total when the relative checkbox in the  is checked, but I am struggling with the selector logic. Can anyone point me as to where I am going wrong, I am a beginner with JQuery. Here is what I have

```
function calculateSelected(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('tr input:checked .price').each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
        });
    $('#total').html(sum)
}
```

And this is a simplified version of the table

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" value='1' /><td>
<td class='price'>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" value='1' /><td>
<td class='price'>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" value='1' /><td>
<td class='price'>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" value='1' /><td>
<td class='price'>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total<td>
<td id='total'></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you debugged this with Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) to see if there are any particular parts that are failing?

Comment: It runs fine but I assume teh slector is wrong as it doesnt return a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this selecting exactly?

```
$('tr input:checked .price')
```

How is there a child of your input?  If you want to select the next td with class price you can do:

```
$('tr input:checked').parent().next('td.price')
```

Comment: i am trying to select the value in the cell with class='price' for the row that has its checkbox checked

Comment: Check my ninja update :) I just noticed you had posted your mark-up so i fixed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Very nice, my only problem is in my real world table it has X amount of collumns so I can't jump to the next <td>. Hoever the 'price' is always the last td in the tr if that helps?

Comment: You're not jumping to the next immediate column.  You're jumping to the first td.price.  So it doesn't matter if its immediately after or the last td in the row.  By passing in a selector td.price it will only find any td with class price.

Comment: No prob, Be sure to accept the answer if its the one that works for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Much like Mark's answer you could use the [Siblings method](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) too.

```
$('tr input:checked').parent().siblings('td.price')
```